# PHP commas for thousands without ending .00

Tags: php

I need to add commas for thousands place without the function adding .00 to end. 
Like so
10,000.00
I want 10,000

Comment: Which PHP function? Please show some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$number = 1234.56;
echo number_format($number); // 1,235
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$num = 10000;
$formatted = number_format($num); // '10,000'
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/NdzGi)